# If v-w belongs to U (vector subspace) then v and w belongs to U?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm reviewing the proof 3.87 in Sheldon Axler's book. 
I have a question: If v-w belongs to U (vector subspace) then v and w belongs to U?

The theorem says: 
Suppose U is a subspace of V and v,w belongs to U. Then the following are
equivalent:
a) v-w belongs to U
b) v+U=w+U

Comment: $\Leftarrow$ is trivial. So lets look at $\Rightarrow$. Assume $v-w\not\in U$. Then it can't be the case that $v$ and $w$ in $U$. So, $v,w\in U$ if and only if $v-w\in U$.

(I suppose that $v,w\in U$ was meant, not v+U = w+U$

Comment: The theorem being quoted is 3.85, not 3.87 in Linear Algebra Done Right. Also, the hypothesis is that v and w belong to V, not U.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that $v$ and $w$ belong to  $U$. [Take $v=w$ with $v \notin U$ for a counter-example].

But it is true that $v+U=w+U$: Let $x \in v+W$. Then $x=v+y$ with $y \in U$. Now $x=w+(v-w)+y=w+z$ where $z =v-w+y$. Since $v-w \in U$ we get $z+y \in U$ and  $x \in w+U$. Hence LHS $\subseteq $ RHS. Similarly RHS $\subseteq $ LHS.